# Android TableLayout - Text View and Button inside the same column

Tags: android, button, drawable, shapes, tablelayout

This is the code for my TableLayout:

```html
<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="1200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" >
        
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="ADDRESS"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="TableTitle" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TENANCY"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
           style="TableTitle" />
        
        <TextView
            android:text="LOCATION"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            style="TableTitle" />
         
        <TextView
            android:text="NAME"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
           style="TableTitle" />
        
        <TextView
            android:text="SELECTION"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
   style="TableTitle" />
        
    </TableRow>
```

Then my drawable/cell_shape is as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape= "rectangle"
    android:name="@+id/rec1"  >
   
        <solid android:color="#30383F"
               android:padding="10dp" />
        <scale 
               android:scaleHeight="200"
               android:scaleWidth="200" />
        
        <stroke 
               android:width="1dp"  
               android:color="#D9D9D6" />
        <padding 
               android:left="10dp"  
               android:top="10dp" 
               android:right="10dp"  
               android:bottom="10dp" />

</shape>
```

I can set up the table just fine but my question is am I able to also include a button inside of a column situated to the right of the text view. Is this possible to do?

For example, in the first column I would like it to say "ADDRESS" then a few pixels to the right for there to be a button, all inside of the same column. Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include a relative or linear layout to include a button and text in each column

```
 <TableRow>
<Relativelayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
            android:text="ADDRESS"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="TableTitle" />

<Button 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"


           android:id="@+id/addbtn"
            android:clickable="false"


             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"      
            />
</Relativelayout>
```

Comment: I would UP your answer but I don't have enough rep, mind UP'ing my question?

Comment: When I get 15 rep ill be back to UP your answer